# Golang, changing structs of custom clients MaxIdleConnsPerHost

Tags: go, struct, switch-statement, client

I want to set a custom http client to get several http requests concurrently.
However, I'm relatively new to Golang and I'm facing issues with changing the struct of the clients and the feasibility of what I want to do.

I want to change the Transport of s with the one I created.

A simplified version of my script is:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "github.com/njasm/gosoundcloud"
)

func main() {
    s, err := gosoundcloud.NewSoundcloudApi("client_id", "client_secret", nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

   if err = s.PasswordCredentialsToken("user@mail.com", "password"); err!= nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    os.Exit(1)
    }

    var userID uint64 = 1
    Transport, ok := http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport)
    if !ok {
        fmt.Println("http.DefaultClient is not an http.Client")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    Transport.MaxIdleConnsPerHost = 250
    //Here I would like to change s'Transport so that it handles 250 MaxIdleConns
    member, err := s.GetUser(userID)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Println(member)
}
```

Here are the structs for s

```
type SoundcloudApi struct {
conf       *oauth2.Config
httpClient *http.Client
response   *http.Response
}
```

References:

https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client
https://godoc.org/github.com/njasm/gosoundcloud#SoundcloudApi

Comment: I'd say this is a feature request, any answer here would be a pure hack. You should file an [issue](https://github.com/njasm/gosoundcloud/issues).

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
tr := &http.Transport{DisableKeepAlives: false, MaxIdleConnsPerHost:250} 
client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
```

And assing `client` to `SoundcloudApi.httpClient`

Comment: I think this changes much more than just the Transport

Answer (score 1):

I'm the creator of the gosoundcloud..

First of all thanks for using the library.

Second, as @OneOfOne pointed out, I too believe that any answer to your needs here will be a workaround that we can probably fix with a feature request.

So, I invite you to file an [issue](https://github.com/njasm/gosoundcloud/issues) to discuss the issue further.

I'll be more then glad to help out.